# Upgrading to Rails 5, can't resolve dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-upgrade

Upgrading from Rails 4.2.10 to Rails 5.1.4 results in the error message below. I am not sure how t resolve the dependencies. The ruby version is 2.5.1. Rails 4.2.10 runs without issue and `bundle upgrade` runs without returning any errors.

**Update:** added Gemfile below for reference. When deleting `Gemfile.lock` prior to performing `bundle update`, the below error message is still generated.

**Error Message**

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.4) was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)

web-console (~> 2.0.0.beta3) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
  activemodel (~> 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    jbuilder (~> 2.7.0) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
  activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

rails (~> 5.1.4) was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.4)

Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.1.4)' in any of the sources.Bundler could not 
find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.4) was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)

web-console (~> 2.0.0.beta3) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
  activemodel (~> 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
jbuilder (~> 2.7.0) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
  activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

rails (~> 5.1.4) was resolved to 5.1.4, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
rails (~> 5.1.4)

Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.1.4)' in any of the sources.
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'uglifier',     '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'stripe'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '~> 1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '~> 3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '~> 1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '~> 0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '~> 2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Comment: Remove `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle install` again

Comment: After I perform the update, will I need to add `Gemfile.lock` back into the project and if so do I need to make manual updates to the file before adding it back?

Comment: after you update, new `Gemfile.lock` will be generated, and you **SHOULD** commit that file. No manual changes should be done(or even required to be done) in that file.

Comment: after deleting `Gemfile.lock` I continue to receive the error message.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your `Gemfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem web-console is locking your update process, first change it to a more recent version like:

```
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
```

Then remove `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` also always is good to check the version of the other gems and check the official Rails upgrade process documentation in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html